# Prevent IE popover on embed PDF

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, embed

Is there a way to prevent the native behavior of IE `<embed>` binded to a PDF when hovered ?

I mean the displayed short popup buttons allowing to :

Zoom in and out

Print

Preview

Save

IE Version : 11

[image: IE Popover]

Comment: Hi, the Adobe PDF reader plugin supports query parameter that you can configure the appearance and functionality of the embedded Adobe PDF ActiveX control. eg:
spr16566n2373.pdf?navpanes=0&statusbar=0&toolbar=0&messages=0&zoom=50, Refer to your installed PDF document viewers website for assistance.

Comment: Why do you want to break an helpful native behavior? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Rac I need to do some actions when the document gets printed, so I expect the user to use my own print button. Catching the print event or the click on the print button of the embed would be fine too.

Comment: @RobParsons Could you point me to some documentation regarding what you just wrote ?

Comment: @Ellone a web search returns several http://www.bing.com/search?q=adobe+pdf+reader+query+parameters

Comment: I don't see how this would help me to do what I'm trying to do ? It's for IE browser's embed preview, not for local PDF